# Underfitting, overfitting or good fit?

Tags: model-evaluation, overfitting, accuracy, lstm

I am working with a medical dataset, trying to figure out people with diabetes. I implemented LSTM since the target variable is a categorical one, the accuracy gave %84. I plotted the accuracy training and testing, and the loss training and testing. But I could not explain the graphs. whether there is underfitting, overfitting or good fit!.
According to the next two graphs, could you please help me with explaining them? and is confusion matrix good to evaluate the model in this way?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It might be informative to see error bars on the loss, the test loss is bouncing about a fair bit and implies that the test loss may be minimised in epoch 1.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it was really helpful.